# Safe Codeigniter join query

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have got simple question.

Is query safe like this? Will codeigniter automatically escape the variable?

```
$this->db->join('cities as s', 's.state_id = "'.$GET['state'].'" AND s.id = users.city_id');
```

Comment: No. it's not safe. No, CI will not automatically escape the variable. CI will never **SEE** the variable. it'll just see the string that the variable got inserted into. So in other words, you are utterly and completely vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: so how I can fix it?

Comment: When I do smth like '$this->db-->where('user_id', $id)' CI will escape, right?

Comment: Yes when using Active Record properly it will automatically escape the data, if you're submitting a query manually without active record you can also manually tell CI to escape data with the $this->db->escape($string) function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To escape $_GET['state'], pass it as an argument to [`where()`](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

```
$this->db->join('cities as s', 's.id = users.city_id');
$this->db->where('s.state_id', $_GET['state']);
```